# Creating RFC-4716 specific dsa public-key using openssl

Tags: ssh, openssl, public-key, dsa, ssh-keygen

For the purpose of ssh using public key authentication,

DSA-2048 keypair has been generated using openssl and both are stored locally in PEM format.
Now, for configuring in the server side (authorized_keys), public key has to be in the RFC-4716 format.

Usually as a practice, for getting this key, ssh-keygen is typically used with options as,

```
ssh-keygen -y -f private_key.pem
```

which returns the corresponding public key(RFC-4716) that has to be configured in the server side.

Without ssh-keygen, Is there a possibility in openssl itself to generate the RFC-4716 specific public key from the openssl generated public (or) private key?

Comment: i don't understand your question, you can generate with ssh-keygen, I hope is an easier way:

`$ ssh-keygen -ef ./dsaprivkey.pem -m RFC4716 

---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "2048-bit DSA, converted by root from mx"
AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAAIBAP9dWpZIOlBsm2jq6k9YYJDhFn8p1oYC6OWH0USVDtvpmFCZaM
......................
wN7OLEGmFyiEV7nNRqdBY5fGSD78ww==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`